# Hierarchy XML to SQL

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an xml with multiple elements and attributes ( you can see an example below ) and I want to make an SQL Table/Tables from it.

XML example:

```
<prgs>
 <prg Id="1" >
   <name>Xulescu</name>
   <type>Human</type>
   <attribs>
     <attrib>doesn't matter</attrib>
   </attribs>
   <timeZone>doesn't matter</timeZone>
   <URL>doesn't matter/</URL>

 .....
</prgs>
```

I need to make a table like this

```
ID       |      Name
-------------------------
1        |      Xulescu
......
```

Thank you

**Another situation**

What about this ?

```
<schedules type="tip1">
  <schedule prgsId="15361" >
     <event Id="1234" date="2012-10-05">
       <times>
         <time>01:00</time>
       </times>
     </event>
     <event Id="2345" date="2012-10-05">
       <times>
         <time>01:30</time>
       </times>
     </event>
```

The result should be a table

```
    ID     ScheduleID      PrgsID        showId     Date     Time
  .................................................................
   1        xxx            xxxx          1234     2012-10-05   01:00
   2        xxx            xxxx          2345     2012-10-05   01:30
```

ID is an autoincrement field

`ScheduleID, PrgsID` are FK keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @XmlFile XML

SELECT @XmlFile = CAST(BulkColumn AS XML)
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\temp\sample.xml' , SINGLE_BLOB) AS XMLDATA

SELECT
    ID = Prgs.value('@Id', 'int'),
    Name = Prgs.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    @XmlFile.nodes('/prgs/prg') AS XTbl(Prgs)
```

If your file contains this XML:

```
<prgs>
 <prg Id="1" >
   <name>Xulescu</name>
   <type>Human</type>
</prg>
 <prg Id="2" >
   <name>Xulescu2</name>
   <type>Human</type>
</prg>
</prgs>
```

you'll get this output:

```
ID  Name
------------
1   Xulescu
2   Xulescu2
```

**Update:** for your additional scenario - how about this? (*assuming you already have your XML structure in a `@XML` variable*):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(ScheduleID, PrgsID, ShowId, [Date], [Time])
   SELECT
       Sched.value('@prgsId', 'int'),
       Sched.value('@prgsId', 'int'),
       Events.value('@Id', 'int'),
       Events.value('@date', 'date'),
       Events.value('(times/time)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
   FROM
       @XML.nodes('/schedules/schedule') AS XTbl(Sched)
   CROSS APPLY
       Sched.nodes('event') AS XTbl2(Events)
```

Not sure how / which attribute you want in `ScheduleId` and `PrgsId` - I only see one `PrgsId` attribute on `<schedule>` ...

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I'll be back if I need more help .

Comment: @user1607079: updated my response, showing how to load an external XML file first. This file **must be** on the SQL Server machine's harddrive. If that SQL Server machine is *not* your local PC, that SQL Server machine **cannot** read your own local harddisk - the file must be on the server machine in that defined directory

Comment: But, what about if I have like this:  @input.nodes('/schedules') AS XTbl(Schdl)    and I want to extract Tip = Schdl.value('@type', 'varchar(MAX)')    . Foreach 'tip' I have Name and Id defined above ( your answer - I extract them from here @input.nodes('/schedules/schedule/lala') AS XTbl(Prgs))

Comment: @user1607079: please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: either **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information - or ask a whole new question! Thank you.

Comment: @user1607079: updated my response to include your additional scenario

Comment: Thank you.That is what I was searching for ( that cross apply command ). Yes, I already have XML-s